# How to get direct SQL by executing API?

Tags: magento-1, collection, product-collection, sql

I want to get the actual SQL for the following code:

```
$array = array('wbk002c','wbk000','wbk001','wbk002L','wbk000xs','wbk000xl','wbk002M','wbk002c-Black-XS','wbk002c-Black-S');
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('configurable','simple'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $array))
;
```

I enabled mysql query log and garbed the sql as the following:

```
           88 Query SET SQL_MODE=''
           88 Query SET NAMES utf8
           88 Query SELECT `core_website`.`website_id`, `core_website`.`code`, `core_website`.`name` FROM `core_website`
           88 Query SELECT `core_store`.`store_id`, `core_store`.`code`, `core_store`.`name`, `core_store`.`website_id` FROM `core_store` ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC
           88 Query SELECT `core_config_data`.`scope`, `core_config_data`.`scope_id`, `core_config_data`.`path`, `core_config_data`.`value` FROM `core_config_data`
           88 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_store` AS `main_table` ORDER BY CASE WHEN main_table.store_id = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, main_table.sort_order ASC, main_table.name ASC
           88 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_website` AS `main_table` ORDER BY main_table.sort_order ASC, main_table.name ASC
           88 Query SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_store_group` AS `main_table` ORDER BY main_table.name ASC
           88 Query SELECT `eav_entity_type`.* FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE (`eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_code`='catalog_product')
           88 Query SELECT `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 4)
           88 Query SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (((`e`.`type_id` = 'configurable') OR (`e`.`type_id` = 'simple'))) AND (`e`.`sku` IN('wbk002c', 'wbk000', 'wbk001', 'wbk002L', 'wbk000xs', 'wbk000xl', 'wbk002M', 'wbk002c-Black-XS', 'wbk002c-Black-S'))
           88 Query SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (282, 511, 510, 283, 877, 881, 880, 284, 878)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('194', '145', '176', '192', '198', '208', '196', '195', '92', '199', '197', '179', '201', '182', '184', '207', '188', '200', '100', '139', '193', '181', '183', '141', '132', '129', '190', '191', '81', '189', '209', '175', '89', '124', '127', '128', '186', '187', '180', '125', '178', '96', '177', '122', '146', '144', '140', '142', '102', '126')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (282, 511, 510, 283, 877, 881, 880, 284, 878)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('205', '202', '106', '72', '203', '204', '83', '101', '73', '210', '185')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (282, 511, 510, 283, 877, 881, 880, 284, 878)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('206', '117', '103', '212', '143', '95', '123', '147', '85', '112', '131', '88', '84', '82', '119', '118', '71', '109', '107', '130', '86', '113', '211', '87', '114', '97', '98')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (282, 511, 510, 283, 877, 881, 880, 284, 878)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('79', '148', '90', '99', '120', '137', '136', '75', '76', '91', '80')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (282, 511, 510, 283, 877, 881, 880, 284, 878)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('104', '105', '93', '94', '77', '78')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0)
           88 Query SELECT `cataloginventory_stock_status`.`product_id`, `cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status` WHERE (product_id IN('282', '511', '510', '283', '877', '881', '880', '284', '878')) AND (stock_id=1) AND (website_id=1)
           88 Quit
```

The problem is that the SQL printed out are separated but not in one SQL, anyone knows how to combine the above SQL in query log in one SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to print SQL query for your custom product collection. Please use below code:

```
echo $productCollection->getSelect();
```